# Can someone show me how to solve these matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

I’m in grade 11 in Romanian high school, and I have a math homework and I simply don’t know how to solve it, seriously, and it is difficult to understand it. [image: Test1 and test 2] [image: Recapitulative exercises]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone please solve these exercises? I simply don’t know how to solve this, and the teacher is coming and I need this to be done fast as you can, I just say that I need help in this. In case you don’t know how to read, you can use google translate. I will be very glad if you would solve this exercises. I really need help in this. And plus, I don’t have time, the teacher is coming and I need to be 100% prepared, can you help me on this?

Comment: You have a 21 question test to do urgently and can’t do a single part of a question?

Comment: @DanRobertson I wish I could do a single past of a question.

Comment: What happened that you can not do a single question? Did you miss classes due to illness?

Comment: For now,you should just ask help from your friends and hope they help you.MSE helps you analyze your difficulties not just help you literally solve them without any ounce of contribution from your side

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan It’s hard to understand, some understand easily and some hard. And, I’m trying to pay attention in class.

Comment: Alternately you could ask your teacher. I presume that your teacher will be most willing to help.

Comment: At least show some effort in research. Do you know what a matrix is?

Comment: Oh my God thats the baccalaureat in romania...you will never get it if you dont do your homework daily...

Comment: Interestingly, do you know Romanian? I don't and I have no way of helping you out until I can read the question.

Comment: Question 1 wants to know which values of $x$ give you a (non-)invertable matrix. I.e. for which values of $x$ the determinant is (non-)zero. So work out the determinant (which you were presumably taught how to do. This gives a quadratic equation in $x$ and you should solve it. For the next part set $x=2$ to get a matrix of integers and follow the steps which you have been taught to invert a matrix

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yeah but, I feel shame that the teacher comes and founds that I have done only few exercises, and I don’t like this, and I wish that I can show her that I have done 100% whole homework and since we entered in winter vacation and we had 4 weeks of vacation, I forgot to do my homework, and now the clock is ticking fast and I don’t have enough time.

Comment: Google Translate is completely incompetent at translation (true experience) and I would have to _type_ in the Romanian sentences to get (somewhat) a translation.

Comment: @Isham No no, I hope that I will get bacalaureat. I hope that I will pass this exam.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan you don’t really need to read Romanian, you can mostly look at the maths and guess what the question is about. Romanian is a Romance language and similar to French/Italian/Latin and most maths words are borrowed from French/English so it isn’t too hard to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Well as the saying goes: Procrastination is bad. If you know the formulae you could easily solve this problem. Do you need the formulae for (as much as I understand from the comments) finding the determinant and the  inverse of a matrix?

Comment: Whats the title of the book ? Maybe there is a solution manual on the web ? So you can work and check the answers ?

Comment: Can anyone help me with reading question number $4$ ? I am trying hard but not being a native English speaker does not help.

Comment: And I am completely lost on $3$.

Comment: @Isham it is “MATEMATICĂ M2” de la editura Prior&Books

Comment: I googled for an answer booklet but I am unable to understand which site leads to what. @AlexA you have to find it yourself. My sincere apologies.

Comment: For question 2 you can rewrite the simultaneous equations into a 3x3 matrix $M$ which contains numbers and simple expressions in $m$. Then the problem becomes $M\mathbf x=(1,2,3m)$ where $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$ and those two vectors are actually column vectors. The equations are soluble if $M$ is invertable which happens if $\det M\ne 0$ so work out the determinant in terms of $m$ and for which values of $m$ it is not zero. For part $b$ you set $m=3$ and compute $M^{-1}$ and then $\mathbf x = M^{-1}(1,2,9)$ is the answer.

Comment: @Isham In here it only gives you tests and exercises but at the end there’s only the result of your exercise, and does not shows you how to solve it.

Comment: Alex thats true but you know these exercices in your book are classic exercices on Matrices. You can find tuto on the web to learn how to calculate inverse matrices ...and determinant.

Comment: @Isham Ok, I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: Question 3 looks like a word problem which can be converted into simultaneous equations which should then be converted into a matrix, inverted and solved. The fourth problem (Testul 2 problem 1) just wants you to work out inverse matrices. Follow steps that you learnt. The next problem specifies a 3x3 matrix $A$ in a strange way (I’m not sure what $C_{2i}^i$ means) and then wants you to solve $AX=B$ so invert $A$ and find $X=A^{-1}B$. The later problems seem to be more of the same. P97 problem 3 is a “write it down and use your brain” problem. Problem 4 is computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m putting this in an answer even though I won’t write down a (worked) solution to any of the exercises. The exercises are based first on being able to do these things with matrices:

1. Calculate determinants of 2x2 and 3x3 matrices (which may contain letters as well as numbers)
2. Multiply matrices (which may contain letters) together (and square matrices)
3. Multiply matrices by vectors
4. Understand the conditions for an inverse of a matrix to exist
5. Compute inverses of 2x2 and 3x3 matrices (just of numbers as far as I can tell)
6. Solve $AX=B$ for $X$ when $B$ is a known vector and $A$ a known square matrix

And these things related to matrices:

7. Convert a system of linear equations into a single matrix equation
8. Understand how this matrix relates to the solubility of the linear system
9. Get the solution to the linear system out of the solution to the matrix equation.

Some of the problems look like they might want Gaussian elimination or consideration of solving $AX=B$ where $B$ is 4x1, $X$ is 3x1, and $A$ is $4x3$. Other later problems look like they want you to apply the above techniques but with a bit more algebra and brain power in the middle.

Hopefully all the above numbered things are explained in your textbook. If they aren’t, such material should be available online.